# On-the-fly package installation fails (and install using Package Manager also fails)

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I have successfully used Texmaker for years with Miktex. I had it set to on-the-fly package installation and still do - in Miktex options, `Package installation` `Install missing packages on-the-fly` is set to `Yes`. `Package repository` is set to the same as worked successfully before: `http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`
(i am using MiKTeX 2.9, and Texmaker 5.0.3 (I understand 5.0.4 is available))

The problem I have is that when I go to compile in Texmaker, I get "file not found". In Package Manager, if I try any of the options under `Repository` such as `Change Package Repository` or  `Synchronise` I get this message window appear:

[image]

I get the same window come up when I look for the missing package in the list in package manager, and click install. At first I get the below message window:

[image]

and click 'OK' but then I get the same problem report as above (the 'no data' one)
I get other Problem Report windows come up for the Miktex Update Wizard, `MiKTeX encountered an internal error.`, Miktex Configuration Utility: `The Miktex configuration utility failed` and Miktex Update (Admin) app and I get the below 'no data' message. Should I be trying to uninstall and reinstall everything again, with newest versions?

[image]

Now with the newest versions installed of both Miktex and Texmaker, I can see the Console, but it is getting stuck installing new packages. (Repository is set to 'somewhere on the internet')
[image]

Comment: Go to the miktex console and check if there are pending updates (do it in user and admin mode).

Comment: Hi Ulrike. I tried looking for the console by typing miktex console into the windows start menu but only web results came up. I've tried the Miktex Update (admin) app but i trust you mean something else?

Comment: If you don't have the miktex console but only the update manager your miktex is quite old. You can try to update with it, but there is no garanty that it will work.

Comment: I have installed the newest version of Miktex and reinstalled Texmaker. I saw the Miktex console and it did the updates it listed after installation. It no longer throws an error if I try to install a new package, but it is taking a very long time... I tried to install a package and it gets stuck (I added an image to the original question)